# Not able to retrieve callback parameters

Tags: callback

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

Array.prototype.filter2 = function(){

        var fir = arguments[0];

        var sec = arguments[1];

        alert(fir);

        alert(sec);

        var arr2 = new Array();

        for(var item=0; item<this.length;item++){
              alert(this[item]);  // 1 section
              if(sec.call(this[item],fir)){
                   arr2.push(this[item]);
              }
        }
        return arr2;
}


function xyz (ele ,x){

       alert(x);
       alert(ele);
       return ele > x;
}


arr.filter2(2,xyz);
```

Till 1'st its running fine but while passing the argument to the callback... x is being alerted as "undefined" whereas ele = fir

Comment: Which language? Which framework? Can you give us a little bit of the actual error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is simple and straight:

either call your function normally,.. i.e

```
Array.prototype.filter2 = function(){

    var fir = arguments[0];

    var sec = arguments[1];

    alert(fir);

    alert(sec);

    var arr2 = new Array();

    for(var item=0; item<this.length;item++){
          alert(this[item]);  // 1 section
          if(sec(this[item],fir)){
               arr2.push(this[item]);
          }
    }
    return arr2;
```

}

Or if you still want to stick with javascript .call(), then simply use it like this:

```
Array.prototype.filter2 = function(){

    var fir = arguments[0];

    var sec = arguments[1];

    alert(fir);

    alert(sec);

    var arr2 = new Array();

    for(var item=0; item<this.length;item++){
          alert(this[item]);  // 1 section
          if(sec.call({},this[item],fir)){
               arr2.push(this[item]);
          }
    }
    return arr2;
```

}

call() and apply() are predefined JavaScript function methods. Both methods can be used to invoke a function, and both methods must have the owner object as first parameter.

You can read more about this by clicking [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp) and find it under heading **Invoking a Function with a Function Method**

Comment: Correct but i think we should pass "this" instead of a new "{}" empty object as it compiles to current scope...